# Protractor: Unable assign ElementFinder from ElementArrayFinder.map()

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm experiencing very strange behavior in Protractor.  Basically I want to loop into an `ElementArrayFinder` and map them into new objects:

```
get endStep(): promise.Promise<any> {

    let items = element.all(By.css('g[end-step]')).map(elm => {
      return {
        container: elm,
        type: "type"
      };
    });
    return items;
  }
```

Test:

```
 page.endStep.then(s => {
      expect(s.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      expect(s.every(x => x != null)).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Code above is not working and I get the following error in console:

> npm ERR! Exit status 3221225725 npm ERR! Failed at the
>   xxxx.xxx.e2e@1.0.0 e2e script 'protractor'. npm ERR! Make sure you
>   have the latest version of node.js and npm installed...

This code however works:

```
get endStep(): promise.Promise<any> {

    let items = element.all(By.css('g[end-step]')).map(elm => {
      return {
        container: elm.getAttribute,
        type: "type"
      };
    });
    return items;
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: No idea. Sorry...

Comment: @BenAston I bet you didn't even read it! :)

Comment: The NPM error is... an NPM error, which sounds unrelated

Comment: @BenAston I have spend several hours now to understand this!! The problem is I can't debug protractor ... put a break point bla bla

Comment: Try browser.debugger();